# Group by common array keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$sortMod = [
    [
        'group_id'  => 1,
        'group_name'=>'Home',
        'module_id' => 1,
        'mod_name'  => 'Home',
        'mod_link'  => '/home',
        'var_name'  => 'home'
    ], [
        'group_id'=> 2,
        'module_id' => 2,
        'mod_name' => 'Numbers',
        'mod_link' => '/number_mapping',
        'var_name' => 'numbermap'
    ], [
        'group_id'=> 2,
        'module_id' => 70,
        'mod_name' => 'DR Plan',
        'mod_link' => '/dr_plan',
        'var_name' => 'dr_plan'
    ], [
        'group_id'=> 3,
        'module_id' => 8,
        'mod_name' => 'Reporting',
        'mod_link' => '/reporting',
        'var_name' => 'reporting'
    ], [
        'group_id'=> 3,
        'module_id' => 80,
        'mod_name' => 'Scheduler',
        'mod_link' => '/scheduler',
        'var_name' => 'scheduler'
    ]
];
```

I want to group the result by `group_id`;

```
$sortMod = [
  [
    'group_id'  => 1,
    'group_name'=>'Home',
    'module_id' => 1,
    'mod_name'  => 'Home',
    'mod_link'  => '/home',
    'var_name'  => 'home'
  ], [
    'group_id'=> 2,
    [
      'module_id' => 2,
      'mod_name' => 'Numbers',
      'mod_link' => '/number_mapping',
      'var_name' => 'numbermap'
    ], [
      'module_id' => 70,
      'mod_name' => 'DR Plan',
      'mod_link' => '/dr_plan',
      'var_name' => 'dr_plan'
    ]
  ], [
    'group_id'=> 3,
    [
      'module_id' => 8,
      'mod_name' => 'Reporting',
      'mod_link' => '/reporting',
      'var_name' => 'reporting'
    ], [
      'module_id' => 80,
      'mod_name' => 'Scheduler',
      'mod_link' => '/scheduler',
      'var_name' => 'scheduler'
    ]
  ]
];
```

Currently I have this:

```
$groups = [];
$modules = array();
```

I am iterating  over the array `$sortMod` and group it by `group_id` where multiple `module_id` appears i.e `group_id` 2 and 3 has multiple modules in them. So the result will look what is stated above. Although I know I can have a flag variable `$groupExist` set to false by default and when the group is pushed into the `$groups` array, the value is set to false. Then have an if statement check if the value is true, then push just the module values :

```
foreach($sortMod as $val) {
  if(!array_key_exists($val['group_id'],$groups)){
    $groups[$val['group_id']] = [];
  }
  $groups[$val['group_id']][] = $val;
} 


echo '<pre>';
print_r($groups);
echo '<pre>';
```

Comment: I don't follow. I `var_dump()` your code and it seems to be the way you asked? Or no? EDIT: nevermind, I see where the difference is.

Comment: Not all, I want the expected result to be like this:

[
  ['group_id'=> 2,
    [
    'module_id' => 2,
    'mod_name' => 'Numbers',
    'mod_link' => '/number_mapping',
    'var_name' => 'numbermap'
    ],
    [
    'module_id' => 70,
    'mod_name' => 'DR Plan',
    'mod_link' => '/dr_plan',
    'var_name' => 'dr_plan'
    ]
],    ,
 ['group_id'=> 3,
    [

Comment: @GytisTenovimas at the moment the group_id is created for each module_id even tho it appears multiple time

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_reduce` to group the array. If you don't want to make a multidimensional array if the group has only one element, you can use `array_map`

```
$sortMod = .. //Your array here.

$grouped = array_reduce($sortMod, function($c, $v){
    $c[ $v['group_id'] ][] = $v;
    return $c;
}, array());

$result = array_map(function ($n) {
    if ( count($n) === 1 ) return $n[0];       //Since the group has one element. Return the element 0.

    $newN = array();                           //Contruct the new format for 2 or more elements.
    $newN['group_id'] = $n[0]['group_id'];     //Add the group_id
    foreach($n as $value)                      //Loop thru the array, remove the group_id and push.
    {
        unset($value['group_id']);
        $newN[] = $value;
    }

    return $newN;
}, $grouped );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 1
            [group_name] => Home
            [module_id] => 1
            [mod_name] => Home
            [mod_link] => /home
            [var_name] => home
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 2
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 2
                    [mod_name] => Numbers
                    [mod_link] => /number_mapping
                    [var_name] => numbermap
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 70
                    [mod_name] => DR Plan
                    [mod_link] => /dr_plan
                    [var_name] => dr_plan
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 3
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 8
                    [mod_name] => Reporting
                    [mod_link] => /reporting
                    [var_name] => reporting
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 80
                    [mod_name] => Scheduler
                    [mod_link] => /scheduler
                    [var_name] => scheduler
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @GytisTenovimas works like a charm!

Comment: Happy to help @Raphael :)

Comment: Yours is also great @Syscall :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic custom function like so:

```
function array_group_by($a, $i, $rem = true){
  foreach($a as $v){
    $k = $v[$i];
    if($rem){
      unset($v[$i]);
    }
    $t[$k][] = $v;
  }

  return $t;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_group_by($sortMod, 'group_id'));
echo '<pre>';
```

And [here](https://pastebin.com/0R8dtEJL) is the output.

A `group id` is supposed to be unique anyways, while this output is not what you specifically wanted it makes a more usable array to loop over.

The first key is the group_id. The following arrays that are in the group array contains are the "modules".

Optionally, you can use `array_group_by($sortMod, 'group_id', false);` to keep the `group_id` within that array.

Now when looping over it:

```
foreach(array_group_by($sortMod, 'group_id') as $groupid => $modules){
  echo "$groupid is the group_id and contains " . count($modules) . " modules";
  foreach($modules as $module){
    echo "Hi from " . $module['module_id'];
  }
}
```

In my opinion, short and reusable code is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some little modifications to your code would make a something like that

```
$group = [];
foreach ($sortMod as $val){
    $current_id = $val['group_id'];
    unset($val['group_id']);
    if (!array_key_exists($current_id ,$group)){
        $group[$current_id] = array();
    }
    $group[$current_id][] = $val;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($groups);
echo '<pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your `$val` into the group using the `group_id`. If you find this key, you can create the `group_id` key. If you find it again, and it's an array, append to it.

```
$groups = [];
foreach($sortMod as $val)
{
    $group_id = $val['group_id'];

    if (!isset($groups[$group_id])) { // First case
        $groups[$group_id] = $val ;
        continue;
    }

    // regroup if 'group_id' is not an array
    if (!is_array($groups[$group_id]['group_id']))
    {
        unset($groups[$group_id]['group_id']);
        $groups[$group_id] = ['group_id' => $group_id, $groups[$group_id]] ;
    }

    // append the new group
    unset($val['group_id']);
    $groups[$group_id][] = $val ;
}
// optionnal (to remove group_id keys)
$groups = array_values($groups);
print_r($groups);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 1
            [group_name] => Home
            [module_id] => 1
            [mod_name] => Home
            [mod_link] => /home
            [var_name] => home
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 2
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 2
                    [mod_name] => Numbers
                    [mod_link] => /number_mapping
                    [var_name] => numbermap
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 70
                    [mod_name] => DR Plan
                    [mod_link] => /dr_plan
                    [var_name] => dr_plan
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 3
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 8
                    [mod_name] => Reporting
                    [mod_link] => /reporting
                    [var_name] => reporting
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [module_id] => 80
                    [mod_name] => Scheduler
                    [mod_link] => /scheduler
                    [var_name] => scheduler
                )

        )

)
```